# How to add click event for ExtJS tab in tabpanel

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have tabpanel, by default all the tabs will be in disabled state. Based on the condition some tabs will be enabled I have done that part. Now I want to add click event for the tabs, I tried with tabchange but the problem is when I enable a tab in runtime tabchange event is triggered but I want it to be triggered when user clicks on a tab.

```
var empTabPanel= new Ext.tab.Panel({
        id: 'emptabpanel',
        width: '100%',
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'hbox',
        items: [{
                title: 'Personal Details',
                border: 0,
                id: 'PERSONAL_DETAILS'
            },{
                title: 'Department Details',
                border: 0,
                id: 'DEP_DETAILS'
            },{
                title: 'Leave Details',
                border: 0,
                id: 'LEAVE_DETAILS'
            }]
    });
```

Comment: try to use suspendEvent function at run time. when your operation is finish use resumeEvent function.

Comment: Thanks D.V it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already write in comment but most of people not see comment that's why I write this in post.

try to use **suspendEvent** function at run time. when your operation is finish use **resumeEvent** function.

**How to use above to function?**

```
tabPanel.suspendEvent ( eventName ) 
tabPanel.resumeEvent ( eventName )
```

--> **Don't forgot to resumeEvent**

Thanks..:)

Answer (score 0):

you can add a default listener

```js
    var empTabPanel= new Ext.tab.Panel({
          ...
         defaults: {
              handler: function(item){
                ...
                if(item is tab1){
                   // active/inactive
                }
                else if(){}...
              }
            },
            items: [{
                    title: 'Personal Details',
                    border: 0,
                    id: 'PERSONAL_DETAILS'
                },{
                    title: 'Department Details',
                    border: 0,
                    id: 'DEP_DETAILS'
                },{
                    title: 'Leave Details',
                    border: 0,
                    id: 'LEAVE_DETAILS'
                }]
                
           });
```